# Web Page Smooth Rounded Corners CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Here is a link that provides free CSS samples. [Black Coffe](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/blackcoffee/) However when i download and open it in visual studio the design time html is all blocks but when it is compiled it then renders with nice rounded corners and nice format. I cannot see where they are doing this in html or css. Can anyone help. I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a background image. The link the image is [here](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/previews/blackcoffee/images/img02.jpg), and you can see the rounded corners. The Visual Studio designer is probably just not showing it correctly.

Comment: i downloaded the zip. and opend the image, but i doesn't show the rounded corners, its just a rectangle.

Comment: @tmax: I did the same, and while the image is very dark, there are indeed rounded corners. Try bumping up the brightness + contrast in GIMP, and it is more obvious.

Comment: @Tejs yes i see it now, the transparent corners threw me off a bit. Thanks for explaining